# Swift generics for Real and Complex that allow isApproximatelyEqual

Tags: swift, generics, complex-numbers

I have the following code working but find it rather lacking in elegance to access isAppromatelyEqual for both FloatingPoint types and Complex<T> types.

```
func aboutEquals<T: AlgebraicField>(_ d1: T, _ d2: T) -> Bool  {
    //return d1.isApproximatelyEqual(to: d2)
    if d1 is Complex<Double> { return (d1 as! Complex<Double>).isApproximatelyEqual(to: d2 as! Complex<Double>) }
    if d1 is Complex<Float> { return (d1 as! Complex<Float>).isApproximatelyEqual(to: d2 as! Complex<Float>)}
    if d1 is Complex<Float80> { return(d1 as! Complex<Float80>).isApproximatelyEqual(to: d2 as! Complex<Float80>)}
    if d1 is Float { return (d1 as! Float).isApproximatelyEqual(to: d2 as! Float)}
    if d1 is Double { return (d1 as! Double).isApproximatelyEqual(to: d2 as! Double)}
    if d1 is Float80 { return (d1 as! Float80).isApproximatelyEqual(to: d2 as! Float80)}
    return true
}
```

The first line of the func, which is commented out, //return ... gives an error that T.Magnitude must conform to FloatingPoint. If I add a "where T.Magnitude : FloatingPoint" then the calling function is flagged that the variables calling the the func must have T.Magnitude conforming to FloatingPoint. I use a generic function with T: AlgebraicField to call the global func above with Complex or Real values. How do I tell the compiler to do all these conversions without enumerating them as above.

Comment: "If I add a "where T.Magnitude : FloatingPoint" then the calling function is flagged that the variables calling the the func must have T.Magnitude conforming to FloatingPoint." -- exactly. In what case is that a problem? Are you actually using Float80 values? If so, then you'll need to write custom versions for that because Float80 doesn't conform to Real (or most other things). Float80 isn't supported on Apple Silicon; do you really mean to use it? (Don't add it "just because it exists.") Adding `where T.Magnitude : FloatingPoint` is the correct way to do what you're doing here.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  Your comment got me thinking I was on the right track and gave up on it too early.  I added the constraint "where T.Magnitude : FloatingPoint" to the calling generic function too and all is well.  Regarding Float80, no I haven't used it or tested it so I'll take that recommendation and delete it.  I'll remove aboutEquals entirely and just use isApproximatelyEqual directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a protocol that allows Real and Complex called RealOrComplex, to make it easy to create generic with no need for a where on every struct that wants this capability.  It is as follows:

```
import Numerics
// Set up protocol for Real and Complex<Real> types
protocol RealOrComplex : AlgebraicField where Magnitude : Real {}
// and enumerate types that fit it and that you want to use
extension Complex : RealOrComplex {}
extension Float   : RealOrComplex {}
extension Double  : RealOrComplex {}
```

Its great for making numerical functions and structs generic.